# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am using PyDrive to upload a zip file to google drive. Here is the code Can someone let me know why I am getting this error?

```
def google_drive_folder_upload(drive, fileLoc):
    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title: LogFiles',
                              'mimeType: application/zip'})
    file1.SetContentFile(fileLoc)
    file1.Upload()
```

Error:

> pydrive\apiattr.py", line 83, in update
> for k, v in iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 15; 2 is required

Comment: your file does not contain an alternateLink.  As far as i know zip files cant be opened in Google drive web application there for its not going to have a alternateLink

Comment: I still see the issue. I removed the alternateLink. Let me update above code as well. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an issue with SetContentFile not working for zip files, since I see that the code opens the file in rb mode.   self.content = open(filename, 'rb')

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using 7z or gzip file formats. Here is what's working for me:

```
def upload_zip_file(drive):        
    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'LogData', 'mimeType': 'application/x-7z-compressed'})
    file1.SetContentFile("test.7z")
    file1.Upload()
```